# Selenium HtmlUnit issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

It does not click element in HtmlUnit but works fine on Firefox. 
for the link [Link](http://m.snapdeal.com/brand/apple/mobiles-tablets/?q=ScreenSize_s%3A9%20and%20Above%5EUpto%208%7C&sort=plrty#&isFilter=true&per_source=brandpage&identifier=Apple)

and the element `//*[@align="right"]/a`. The htnmlunit finds the element anchor tag but the tag does not contain `href`.  It clicks the element but does not visit next page.

```
cbean.setDriver(new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38));
```

the driver

```
List<WebElement> wele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@align="right"]/a"));
if(wele.size()>0)
{
    wele.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Please `wait` as hinted in http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork, also make sure you use latest version, and post your complete code.